# Can't find the reason for the error in my code in python

Tags: python, hashmap

I am beginner in Python and learning through Learn Python the Hard Way.

Unfortunately, I keep getting an error and don't know why.

Here's the code:

```
def new(num_buckets=256): # Creates list aMap and fills it with 256 empty lists.
    """ Initializes a Map with the given number of buckets."""
    aMap = []
    for i in range(0, num_buckets):
        aMap.append([])
    return aMap

new()
print aMap
```

strangely enough I keep getting a message saying that aMap is not defined even though I just ran a function creating it as a bunch of empty buckets inside a list.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: er.. but isn't `aMap` only defined and therefore scoped inside your `new` function? do you want to do `print(new())`? or `temp = new() print(temp)`?

Comment: I think you don't quite understand what `return` does, and how variables are scoped.

Comment: You need to handle the return variable. You can do result = new() then do print result;

Comment: You should read up on the basics of [using the return value of functions](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) and [scopes and namespaces in Python](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#python-scopes-and-namespaces).

Comment: Thanks guys. I haven't learned about global variables yet. Seems kind of stupid now that I understand it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`new()` *returns* `aMap`, but you never store that anywhere.  You want:

```
aMap = new()
```

Generally speaking, unless you explicitly state otherwise (via a `global` or `nonlocal`<sup>1</sup> statement), a name only exists in the scope where it was defined.  In this case the name `aMap` only exists inside the function `new`.  To make that name exist outside the function, you need to assign something to it.

<sup><sup>1</sup>Python3.x only</sup>